# Website hangs using FF25 OSX 10.9

Tags: css, macos, firefox

I've encountered a problem that has completely stumped me, and unfortunately I don't really know how to go about trying to diagnose the problem either.

Basically I have a client who's website loads and then just hangs using FF25 on OSX 10.9, it only happens on this website, no other website. I've heard of problems before with this combination that resulted in people having to disable their plugins, so I told them to disable plugins/clear cache and get back to me. They've done this but to no avail. I've also read that it may be a CSS issue with fonts(no idea why it would be).

I've been all over the Mozilla forums but no one has raised such a query that replicated my problem on just a single website. Here probably isn't the best place to raise such an issue, but I'm sure someone must of encountered the same problem and resolved it some way or another.

Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: When I load the page whilst I have the web console up, the page decides to work perfectly? Why is this?

Comment: Please describe "just hangs" in more detail. Do you mean that the browser actually locks up or just that the site doesn't respond to Javascript actions? Can you switch to other tabs and back again? Can you scroll your page? Can you select text on the page? etc?

Comment: The browser goes completely non responsive, can't do anything. Have to force quit the browser and then re-open

Answer (score 0):

There are memory allocation issues that appeared in FF25 (certainly on Windows; FF26 and 27 seem much "better").  These issues seem to be js/heap related.  See, for example, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=936784

You can investigate yourself how the browser is using memory by browsing to about:memory in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little odd that this does not happen if the browser console is open - and even after closing the browser console and refreshing the page it continues to load fine.

What might be happening (or not happening) with the console open which would prevent this error from happening?

We've tested it on 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9 and all three have this problem, but only on Firefox 25.

In response to Codacoder, that bug appears to be related to leaving Firefox unattended and an ongoing incremental memory usage issue - this happens the second the page loads, rendering the browser un-usable and requiring a manual kill of the browser.  Not sure if it's the same issue?

Ruth